# PHP array_map callback function inside function

Tags: php, arrays, array-map

I have a function called `createCost`, and inside that function, I have an `array_map` that takes in an array and a function called `checkDescription` that's inside that `createCost`. Below is an example:

```
public function createCost{

  $cost_example = array();
  function checkDescription($array_item)
  {
    return $array_item;
  }

  $array_mapped = array_map('checkDescription', $cost_example);
}
```

When I run this I get a

```
array_map() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'checkDescription' not found or invalid function name
```

Which to my understanding is that it looked for the function `checkDescription` outside that `createCost` but how can I call `checkDescription` from inside?

Comment: That *should* work, but would fail later for other reasons… how about a simple anonymous function…?

Comment: Nesting functions!?! That's never sensible, and commonly misunderstood, as functions are never actually "nested"... but is your class namespaced, for example?

Comment: @deceze Not really because my understanding of Array_Map is that it looks for the function that exists outside the Map...

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that, but it works just fine: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44927275/476

Comment: @deceze No worries.... it's all sorted because of the answer below

Comment: @MarkBaker I'm using Laravel so my `createCost` is actually a Route Function and I needed to use a array_map to process that Route's data... and with each route, I'm processing the array of arrays with array_map... 

The answer below sorted my issue

Comment: This is a valid question and actually a common issue (the views prove it) as such a scenario is not shown in the documentation (as it is assumed that a function should not be nested).

Comment: Because there is no samle data / context / expected result, I find this question Unclear.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Do like this

```
public function createCost(){
    $cost_example = array();
    $array_mapped = array_map(function ($array_item){
        return $array_item;
    }, $cost_example);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Why not assign the function to a variable?

```
public function createCost{

  $cost_example = array();
  $checkDescription = function ($array_item) {
                          return $array_item;
                      }

  $array_mapped = array_map($checkDescription, $cost_example);
}
```

Isn't this more readable too?